# Command pattern question; clarification needed; Java

Tags: java, command, design-patterns

Suppose you have a command as follows:

```
public class PublishLastFiveCommand implements Command {
    private Producer p;

    public PublishLastFiveCommand(Producer p) {
    this.p = p;
    }

    public void execute() {\    
    p.publishLastFive();
    }
}
```

Additionally producer allows you to

```
public void publishLastFive() {
    System.out.println("publishing last 5");
}

Command c;

public void setCommand(Command c) {
    this.c = c;
}

public void execute() {
    c.execute();
}
```

**Question:**

Intended usage is:

```
Command publish5 = new PublishLastFiveCommand(p);
p.setCommand(publish5);
p.execute();
```

Is there a graceful way for me to protect against:

```
p.publishLastFive()
```

being called directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, i got it.

Publishing in case, others may have the same question.

**On command:**

```
@Override
public void execute() {
    p.setCommand(this);      <-- add this line
    p.publishLastFive();
}
```

**On producer**

```
public void publishLastFive() {
    if (c != null) {         <--- add null check
        System.out.println("publishing last 5");
    } 
}

Command c = null;

public void setCommand(Command c) {
    this.c = c;
}

public void execute() {
    c.execute();
    c = null;                <-- once done executing, set command to null
}
```

**Ad a result:**

works:

```
publish5.execute();
```

works:

```
p.setCommand(publish5);
p.execute();
```

does not work, as desired

```
p.publishLastFive();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the `publishLastFive()` method protected, only objects in the same package can access that method.  (Assuming that your PublishLastFiveCommand class is in the same package, it can invoke that method without a problem, but client code in other packages cannot directly invoke `publishLastFive()`.

I don't understand what you mean about preventing `new PublishLastFiveCommand(p).execute();`.  Why do you want to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK not at all, because execute() is public.